# 3 level sub-category system messed up at 3rd level

Tags: php, mysql, arrays, menu

I want to create a page with a menu like this:

```
main1
 >sub1.1
   >sub1.1.1
   >sub1.1.2
 >sub1.2
   >sub1.2.1
main2
 >sub2.1
   >sub2.1.1
   >sub2.1.2
 >sub2.2
   >sub2.2.1
```

But what's currently happening is this:

```
main1
 >sub1.1
 >sub1.2
   >sub1.1.1
   >sub1.1.2
   >sub1.2.1
main2
 >sub2.1
 >sub2.2
   >sub2.1.1
   >sub2.1.2
   >sub2.2.1
```

Here is my code:

```
<?php 

$categories = array();

// main-categories
$sql = 'SELECT * FROM forum_market_main ORDER BY market_main_id ASC';
$result = mysql_query($sql);

while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)) {
    $categories[$row['market_main_id']] = $row;
}

// sub-categories
$sql = 'SELECT * FROM forum_market_sub ORDER BY market_sub_id ASC';
$result = mysql_query($sql);

while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)) {
    $categories[$row['market_main_id']]['forum_market_sub'][] = $row;
}

// sub2-categories
$sql = 'SELECT * FROM forum_market_sub2 ORDER BY market_sub2_id ASC';
$result = mysql_query($sql);

while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)) {
    $categories[$row['market_main_id']]['forum_market_sub']['forum_market_sub2'][] = $row;
}

print_r($categories);

?>
```

You can see it for yourself here: [click](http://rambazar.com/forum/) - View source mode for easier understanding.

And my bonus question would be a PHP code or whatnot to get this whole menu system displayed nicely.

Thank you very much for your kind help!

Answer (score 1):

I suggest look at this [click](http://www.vbmysql.com/articles/database-design/managing-hierarchical-data-in-mysql) for how to do design your database for hierarchical data.

Comment: Great, now I know what I'm doing this weekend- playing around with this. I shall learn you yet mysql!